# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ converges $\iff$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{b_n}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{b_n}$ are positive term series and $L\in (0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}=L$, prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{b_n}$ converges.

Can anyone help get me started? I am new to proofs involving series and I am not sure what the approach is. I know a few theorems like the divergence test and the cauchy criterion that apply.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

By the definition of limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}=L \iff \exists \bar n\quad \forall n\ge \bar n\quad \frac L 2 \le \frac{a_n}{b_n} \le 2L \iff \frac L 2b_n \le a_n \le 2L b_n$$

Comment: Gimusi.The master at work.Very nice!

Comment: @PeterSzilas Dear Friend, you are always too kind with me! Thanks :)

Comment: I appreciate the hint, but I am not sure where to go from there either.

Comment: @johnny133253 The most important think is that you can follow that as a derivation from the definition of limit. Then let assume that $b_n$ is convergent, what can we conlcude from the latter inequality?

Comment: We can conclude that the series $\sum{a_n}$ converges by the Comparison Test, right?

Comment: @johnny133253 Yes exactly! Then consider $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{b_n}{a_n}}=\frac 1L$ and assume that $\sum a_n$ converges (in the previous comment of course I mean "let assume that $\sum b_n$ converges").

Comment: @johnny133253 Note that with the same idea we can easily prove also the divergence case.

Comment: Thanks! Makes a lot of sense now. Sometimes these analysis proofs appear more difficult then they are.

Comment: @johnny133253 Suppose $\sum b_n$ diverges then from $$a_n \ge \frac L 2 b_n \implies \sum a_n \ge \sum \frac L 2 b_n$$ we conclude that also $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @johnny133253 You aonly need to practice with the proof to get confident with it! Let continue in that way, that's nice! Bye